# How to display a datepicker on a page in laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-4, datepicker

I use following code to display datepicker.
But when i run the application on Firefox, I cant find the datepicker.
I am using Laravel4.2.
Is there any best way to display datepickers?
Is there any CDNs availabele to do this?

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
         {{ Form::label('select','Select an event :') }}
           <select class="form-control input" name="events" id="events" >
            <option selected disabled value="00">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Clicks</option>
                <option value="2">Views</option>
                <option value="3">Loads</option>
                <option value="4">Opens</option>
            </select>
            </th>
            <th>
             {{ Form::label('s_date','From :') }} 
          <input type="date" class="form-control" required id="dp" name="start_date"/>
            </th>
            <th>
             {{ Form::label('t_date','To :') }} 
          <input type="date" class="form-control" required id="dp" name="to_date"/>
         </th>
         <th>
          <input type="button" value="View report" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="displayVals()">
         </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div id="performance">
   
</div>
```

Comment: running your code snippet your date picker shows alright . You have to click the dropdowns. try clicking on the input forms . calendar will show up.
PS make sure your laravel view ends with .blade.php.

Comment: I works, But only in Google chrome, and I am working on Linux too.

Answer (score 2):

See `bootstrap-datepicker` on http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Add markup:

```
<div id="sandbox-container">
    <input type="text" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Add Script:

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({

});
```